# AndroidStudioでクラスを認識しない

Tags: android, android-studio

AndroidStudioでクラスがすべて以下のアイコンになり、コンパイルエラーのコードを書いたときに赤の下線がつきません。ですが普通に実機デバック可能です。
この対策をご教示いただけませんでしょうか。

バージョンなどは下記になります。
AndroidStudio 2.2.3
OS:Windows7 64bit
Java8

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

新しくプロジェクトを作成しても同じ現象です。
gradleは以下になります
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1):

設定に問題があるのでは？
File > Power Save Mode がチェックされてませんか？
あるならチェックをなくせば解決します。

Answer (score 0):

javaのソースとして認識されてないと思います。gradle の sync を 試してみたり、build.gradleを見直して再度 gradle sync すると改善することが多いです。AndroidStudioの再起動も有効だと思います。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。再起動やgradleのsyncの試しましたが直りません。他に要因はございますでしょうか

Comment: `build.gradle`の中は見れますか？可能なら質問に追記するとアドバイスできるかもしれません。

Comment: 追記しました。新しくプロジェクトを作成しても同じ状況です

Comment: 新規プロジェクトでも駄目だとちょっとお手上げですね・・・。再インストールでしょうか・・・。